# jquery buttons are not showing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The buttons in this jquery are not showing;

```
function jqcall() {
     $(document).ready(function () {
           var dlg1 = $("#dialog").dialog({
                  width: 1250,
                  height: 575,
                  autoOpen: false,
                  buttons: {
                      'Ok': function () {
                          $("[id*=Button1]").click();
                      },
                      'Close': function () {
                          $(this).dialog('close');
                      }
                  }
           });

           dlg1.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
     });
}
```

Originally this dialog box was opening on clickig link button in Gridview and also the save button is not working in gridview; it is posting back to server and not showing any error but data is not saving to the database.

Comment: Post your ASP/HTML?

Comment: <div id="dialog" style="display:none">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the use of the initializer options:

- `position: { my: "left top", at: "left top", of: $("#divId") }`

  - Puts the left top of the element at the left top of $("divId").
- `appendTo: "#divId"`

  - Positions the dialog appended within the `#divId` element. Similar to `position`,
- `modal: true`

  - Positions it above all other elements on the page, effectively disabling them while the dialog is open.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dlg1 = $("#dialog").dialog({
    width: 1250,
    height: 575,
    position: { my: "left top", at: "left top", of: $("#divId") },
    autoOpen: false,
    //appendTo: "#divId",
    //modal: true,  
    closeText: "hide",
    title: "Dialog Title",
    buttons: [{
      text: "Ok",
      icons: { primary: "ui-icon-heart" },
      click: doSomething
    }, {
      text: "Close",
      icons: { primary: "ui-icon-heart" },
      click: () => $(this).dialog('close')
    }]
  });
  $("#dialog").dialog( "open" );
});

$("[id*=Button1]").click(doSomething);

function doSomething() {
  console.log("Something");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="divId"></div>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

Comment: @ChetanSarode Try again - you'll need the `position` to be set so it's not off-the-page when it's this big.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

$('#clickMe').click(function(event) {
    var mytext = $('#myText').val();


    $('<div id="dialog">'+mytext+'</div>').appendTo('body');     
 event.preventDefault();

  $("#dialog").dialog({     
   width: 600,
   modal: true,
   close: function(event, ui) {
    $("#dialog").remove();
    }
   });
    }); //close click
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h3 id="clickMe">Open dialog</h3>
<textarea cols="0" rows="0" id="myText" style="display:none">Some hidden text display none</textarea>
```